# Replace row values in a Dataset using LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, linq

```
    DataSet oDSetTest = new DataSet();
    DataTable oT2 = new DataTable();

    oT2.TableName = "Test";
    oT2.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(int));
    oT2.Columns.Add("Age", typeof(int));
    oT2.Columns.Add("Exp", typeof(int));
    oT2.Columns.Add("Data", typeof(string));

    oT2.PrimaryKey = new DataColumn[] { oT2.Columns["ID"] };
    oT2.AcceptChanges();

    oT2.Rows.Add(1, 25, 3,"<<AS>>");
    oT2.Rows.Add(2, 27, 6);
    oT2.Rows.Add(3, 25, 3, "BC");

    oDSetTest.Tables.Add(oT2);
    oDSetTest.AcceptChanges();
```

I want to replace "<<" and ">>" in the dataset using the values "&#60" and "&#62" respectively using LINQ. I don't want to loop the dataset because in the real scenario there are more than 1000 rows.

Comment: `LINQ` is in fact based on the `while` loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't avoid loops with LINQ. But here is LINQ solution:

```
var rowsToUpdate = from r in oT2.AsEnumerable()
                   let data = r.Field<string>("Data")
                   where data != null && 
                         (data.Contains("<<") || data.Contains(">>"))
                   select r;

foreach (var row in rowsToUpdate)
    row.SetField("Data", row.Field<string>("Data")
                            .Replace("<<", "&#60").Replace(">>", "&#62"));
```

Also keep in mind that LINQ is for Querying, not for modifying. It helps you to select data which you want to modify. Then you should use loop to modify data which will be selected by query.

Answer (score 0):

You can also query on the data filed as follows:

```
var rows = oDSetTest.Tables["Test"].Select("Data LIKE '%<<%' OR Data LIKE '%>>%'");
foreach (var row in rows)
{
    row.SetField("Data", row["Data"].ToString().Replace("<<", "&#60").Replace(">>", "&#62"));
}
oDSetTest.AcceptChanges();
```